# sum over primes involving divisor function (variation of the Titchmarsh divisor problem)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions

Does there exist an asymptotic estimate for the following sum over primes
$$
\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\tau(p-1)}{p}\;,
$$
where $\tau(n)=\sum_{d|n}1$ is the divisor function?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, misprint, the argument was supposed to be $\varphi(p)$...

Comment: Where is the $\phi(p)$? In any case, I cannot see anything helpful in the survey of the Titchmarsh divisor problem by Sungjin Kim at UCLA. Tiresomely, I cannot find a date on it! His homepage is http://www.math.ucla.edu/~i707107/

Comment: @almagest It used to say $\tau(p)$, $p-1=\phi(p)$.

Comment: @almagest I wanted to say: the original problem had $\tau(\varphi(p))$...

Comment: Isn't this easily obtained from known formula in the Titchmarsh divisor problem by using Abel summation formula?

Comment: The question now has an answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180725/sum-over-primes-involving-divisor-function-variation-of-the-titchmarsh-divisor.

Answer (score 1):

@almagest, I am sorry that the note was not helpful. I wrote the note and now I included more recent theorems. However, a previous version of my note should have been helpful because of the following from the note:

Let $\tau(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} 1$ be the divisor function. We define the following constants, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
    $$
C_1 =\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)},  $$
    $$
C_2 =C_1 \left(\gamma-\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p^2-p+1}\right)
$$

For any $A>0$, we have

$$
A(x):=\sum_{p\leq x}\tau(p-1)=C_1  x + 2C_2  \mathrm{Li} (x) + B(x)
$$
where $B(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log^A x}\right)$.

Then by partial summation,

$$
\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\tau(p-1)}p = \int_{2-}^{x} \frac1t dA(t) = \left[ \frac{A(t)}t\right] _{2-}^x + \int_2^x \frac{A(t)}{t^2} dt 
$$
$$
=O\left(\frac1{\log x} \right) +\int_2^x \left(\frac{C_1}t + 2C_2 \frac{\mathrm{Li}(t)}{t^2} \right) dt + \int_2^{\infty} \frac{B(t)}{t^2} dt  
$$
$$
=C_1 \log x + 2C_2 \log\log x -C_1 \log 2 - 2C_2 \log\log 2 + \int_2^{\infty} \frac{B(t)}{t^2} dt  +O\left(\frac1{\log x} \right). 
$$